# Rust: Executing dereferenced closure inside a task

Tags: rust

I have some code that takes a Vector of functions and then iterates over them and executes each one at each step. I am trying to incorporate tasks into the for loop so that these function calls can be executed asynchronously instead of having the first one block the second one and so on...

```
let mut arr: Vec<|i32| -> i32> = Vec::new();
arr.push(function1);
arr.push(function2);

let ref num_in = os::args()[1];
let num_str = num_in.to_string();

let num = match from_str::<i32>(num_str.as_slice()) {
    Some(x) => x,
    None => panic!("Not a number"),
};

for f in arr.iter_mut() {
    spawn(proc(){
        println!("{}", (*f)(num.clone()));
    });
};
```

Without the task, and simply doing the `println!` inside the for loop this code runs just fine, but in a blocking way that I am trying to avoid by using tasks. With the task I get these errors and notes...

`error: the trait 'core::kinds::Send' is not implemented for the type '&mut |i32| -> i32'`

`note: the closure that captures 'f' requires that all captured variables implement the trait 'core::kinds::Send'`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

`f` is, like the compiler is telling you, a `&mut |i32|->i32`. It's a borrowed reference to one of the vector elements. Such a borrowed reference cannot be sent across a task boundary. This is an easy rule to prevent dangling pointers and thus memory safety errors because the scope-based lifetime guarantees simply don't work like that if multiple threads are involved.

But even something of type `|i32|->i32` is currently like a borrowed reference (generally) because it borrows its environment. If you don't capture any variables (“empty environment”), you could use `fn(i32) -> i32` instead to get something sendable. You can think of it as a simple function pointer.

Letting other tasks execute something that carries its *own* environment (as in “not borrowed”) is usually done with a `proc`. That's its purpose. You're already using `proc`s for that reason. The compiler just copies `f` into the `proc` which makes the whole `proc` non-sendable because the borrowed reference is non-sendable.

In the near future, we'll get “unboxed closures” which will make `proc`s superfluous. Then, you should be able to use `Vec<Box<FnOnce(i32)->i32 + Send>>` or `Vec<Box<Fn(i32)->i32 + Send>>` as a replacement for `Vec<proc(i32)->i32>`. And creating these kinds of boxes will probably involve the `box` and the `move` keyword as well as a cast to a trait object.

Comment: I have changed the first line to `let mut arr: Vec<fn(i32) -> i32> = Vec::new();` and now I get this error instead:`error: 'arr' does not live long enough`

Comment: @AllTheTime: Please provide a complete example. I forgot to mention: Keep in mind that the vector iterators yield references.